# Making a rectangular-shaped pattern

Tags: java, ascii-art

I'd like someone to suggest a better way to create this pattern in Java which I'm sure is possible:

```
*********
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
*       *
*********
```

I'm working my way through a new Java book and am examining string patterns.

```
public static void drawRectangle() {

    // y axis
    for( int y = 0; y <= 8; y++ )
    {
        if( y == 0 || y == 8 )
        {
            System.out.print( "*********\n" );
            if( y == 8 )
            {
                // Leave loop
                break;
            }
        }

        // x axis
        for( int x = 0; x <= 8; x++ )
        {
            if( x == 0 || x == 8 )
            {
                System.out.print( "*" );
                if( x == 8 )
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print( " " );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Off the top of my head, I'd say that I could replace the values in the loops with constants to work towards. For example:

```
final static int END_POINT = 8;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: When doing a lot of string concatenations, you should instead use a `StringBuilder`.  This is for performance reasons, so it is actually not very important for your problem.

Comment: it may be for this particular problem but I'm sure I'll come across it again at some point. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's ok for a first iteration.

1. But your 2nd iteration should be `drawRectangle(int width, int height)`. That will force you to not hard-code your numbers.
2. Your 3rd iteration should be noticing that your rectangle only has 2 different rows (one row fills up the width with * and the other only has * in the beginning and end).  You might want to make a method `drawHorizontal` to draw the top and bottom and `drawEnds` to draw the sides.  For example

```
    void drawHorizontal(int width) {
      for (int i=0 ; i<width ; i++) {
         System.out.print("*");   /* notice I'm using print() not println() */
      }
      System.out.println("");     /* notice I'm using println() */
    }

    void drawEnds(int width) {
      System.out.print("*");
      for (int i=1 ; i<width-1 ; i++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("*");
    }
```

Comment: Just for your information, [I put together a fast speed test](http://pastebin.com/0p0ck4JQ). Creating a string and outputting the whole string instead of printing single characters is a lot faster. Now that I think about it, iteration 4 should most likely return complete strings anyway.

Comment: @Bobby, yes but I wasn't sure if I should tell the OP about StringBuilder at this point.

Comment: I think a fourth or even fifth iteration with changes up to "I'd do it like this in the end" would be a very good addition and shouldn't be too hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

## Interface suggestions

Anything that can be parameterized instead of hard-coded should be.  I would pass the dimensions to the `Rectangle` constructor.  Then I would create a `draw(PrintStream out)` method.  In other words, the rectangle knows how to draw itself to a `PrintStream` of your choice, whether it's `System.out` or some other output destination.

## Loop Simplification

You can simplify your code by letting `Arrays.fill()` do the boring looping work to populate some buffers.  Then, you only need one `for`-loop to iterate over the rows.  A bonus is that you take advantage of the fact that many of the lines to be printed are identical to each other.

## Solution

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Rectangle {
    private int rows, cols;

    public Rectangle(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    public void draw(PrintStream out) {
        char[] buf = new char[cols];

        Arrays.fill(buf, '*');
        String cap = new String(buf);

        Arrays.fill(buf, 1, cols - 1, ' ');
        String body = new String(buf);

        out.println(cap);
        for (int i = rows - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            out.println(body);
        }
        out.println(cap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Rectangle(8, 8)).draw(System.out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to make Rectangle.

```
public class myclass {
    // Input the size of the Rectangle.

    static int hight = 8;
    static int width = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        line(width);
        for (int m = 0; m < hight - 2; m++) {
            starWithSpace();
            System.out.println();
        }
        line(width);
    }

    public static void space() {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    public static void printStar() {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    public static void starWithSpace() {
        printStar();
        for (int i = 0; i <= hight - 2; i++) {
            space();
        }
        printStar();
    }

    public static void line(int width) {
        for (int header = 0; header <= width; header++) {
            printStar();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: don't just post plain code,practice to give some explanation.

Comment: Note, this answer is locked, and undeleted: it is significant as it provides context for a [meta-tag:faq] meta question: [Should code block(s) as answers always require an explanation?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/855/31503)